# Arduino on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I have an **Arduino DUE**. I have tested it with my switches and LEDs using the **Arduino 1.8.5 interface**. All is just fine, but I needed a better IDE and easier to implement object oriented (ie classes) approach. I long ago stopped thinking in linear programming code.

I have downloaded and am running **Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committer Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)** and used the **Eclipse Marketplace** to install **Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino 2.0** and selected **Package: Arduino SAM Boards (32-bits ARM Cortex-M3)** from the **Arduino Download Package Manager** as per [***Program Your Arduino Like a Pro with the Eclipse C/C++ IDE***](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/april/article4.php).

I have put in the following simple **Blink** program code but, already, I have a problem in the first line **`#include <Arduino.h>`**!: "**Unresolved inclusion: `<Arduino.h>`**"!

Should not the Arduino plug had included the include files and stored a path to them? How do I resolve this?
regards
Josie Hill

**Blink**

For conciseness, I have cleared out all the comments and left the references. It hardly matters anyhoo because the problem is the Arduino include files and their path.

```
  #include <Arduino.h>

/* created 2005 by David A. Mellis
   modified 8 Feb 2010 by Paul Stoffregen
   modified 11 Nov 2013 by Scott Fitzgerald
   modified 9 Jan 2017by Arturo Guadalupi
   This example code is in the public domain.
   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay */

const int ledPin =  LED_BUILTIN;
int ledState = LOW;    
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000;    
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
            previousMillis = currentMillis;   
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

Comment: _"better"_ is relative/personal. [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) edition is free - it might be what you are looking for. ATMEL Studio is VS based. You will also need some kind of add-on - maybe [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualMicro.ArduinoIDEforVisualStudio).

Comment: You should search [softwarerecs.se] for "c++ ide arduino" and see what comes up.  Asking for recommendations on StackOverflow is off-topic.

Comment: I already have Visual Studio Community but compilation failed in so many deep down places in the include files!

Comment: Similarly, I tried ATMEL but I forget the issue there.

Comment: I know why my AVR Studio 5 foxed me! I could not find my DUE board. The processor is an ATMEL ATSAM3X8E-AU in the New Project list?

Comment: I still can't find it!

Comment: Sorry ZDF, "better", although a comparative adjective, in my case it was absolute because I can't see the Arduino 1.8.5 IDE and there seems no way to profile its appearance. That was the significant reason but I also couldn't see how to add classes and include *.h files. Thank you for ansering, it now appears I should install ATMEL Studio 7, which I am now doing.

Comment: Trying Actmel Studio 7 now but still can't find my device: Board sticker: DUE, Chip: ATSAM8X3E, USB label: ATMEGA16U2

Comment: Still no joy with Actmel Studio 7. My device isn't there even after employing what seemed like a solution installing Arduino 1.6.0 to get a file called bossac.exe.

Comment: So now I am try Visual Studio 2015 again with the vMicro plugin. My device is there! I had a few errors involving __Pragma("pack(1)") statements in include files. I changed them to #pragma pack(1) and all went well until...

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  error: C:\Users\Josie Hill\AppData\Local\Temp\VMBuilds\sketch_aug07a\arduino_due_x_dbg\Release\core\syscalls_sam3.c.o: No such file or directory  File: arm-none-eabi-gcc

Comment: Please! What does this mean? I have a fully activated vMicro plug in

Comment: I also had a myriad of error involving a ; was expected or a ) expected in a __ASM statement. However, I kept building, making no changes, and the just suddenly disappeared. Funny, I thought to myself :)

Comment: I cannot give you a specific advice. If you are a novice, you probably have to start with something very simple. Also, do not expect a full c++ standard implementation for Arduino. If your program works with Arduino's standard IDE, it should work with any other one; it is just a matter of configuration.

Comment: Thank you ZDF. I have peace at last. I had Arduino 1.6.0 installed to try a recommended solution with Actmel 7. It didn't work so I replaced it with Arduino 1.8.5, uninstalled Actmel 7 and all is OK with VS 2015 with the vMicro plug in. I am well experienced in most languages. Been writing software since 1970 all all types of 'puters and languages. I am now 70 and I have lost substantial parts of my retinas due to diabetic retinopathy. This means I can easily miss vital points when reading assistance on the web. Bits just go missing! regards

Comment: Why couldn't this be in java? I'll find out soon enough what the shortcomings of the Arduino implementation of C++ are, I guess. Again Thank you ZDF and Thomas Matthews  kind regards

Comment: @JosieH It is nice to see that this serious condition does not keep you back. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ZDF and @ThomasMatthews for your input. I'm happy to report that I solved my problem by **excluding Eclipse** as a contender, reinstalling **Arduino Studio 1.8.5** and installing the **Arduino vMicro** plugin for my already existing **Visual Studio 2015 Community** installation.

There were a few problems with building, mainly with these statements from whatever include file(s) (I never took any notice of which but they soon pop up):

```
_Pragma ("Pack(1)")
_Pragma ("Pack()")
```

I replaced them with:

```
#pragma Pack(1)
#pragma Pack()
```

A few other build issues came up but they seemed to fix themselves after I just viewed their declarations and used a liberal dose of **File > Save All** menu clicks. Curious or what?

Regards